# How does Spiritual Weapon interact with Illusions?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, illusion

There were two [*Silent Image*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/silent-image/)s mimicking a fight between a seemingly helpless woman and a harpy at quite some distance. The PCs (good souls that they are) decided to save the woman, and as soon as able the Oracle cast *Spiritual Weapon* and set it on the harpy.

In Pathfinder, *[Spiritual Weapon](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/spiritual-weapon/)* has no stipulations regarding how it interacts with illusions, although it is laid out pretty clearly otherwise. The spell states:

> A weapon made of force appears and attacks foes at a distance... It strikes the opponent you designate, starting with one attack in the round the spell is cast and continuing each round thereafter on your turn... It strikes as a spell, not as a weapon, so for example, it can damage creatures that have damage reduction. As a force effect, it can strike incorporeal creatures without the reduction in damage associated with incorporeality. The weapon always strikes from your direction. It does not get a flanking bonus or help a combatant get one. Your feats or combat actions do not affect the weapon...

For the illusory side of this interaction, the magic entry for illusion states [emphasis my own]:

> Creatures encountering an illusion usually do not receive saving throws to recognize it as illusory **until they study it carefully or interact with it in some fashion**.

**Would *Spiritual Weapon* count as "interacting with [the illusion] in some fashion"?**

On the spot, as the DM setting a particularly fun trap, I didn't want to give it away quite yet so I did not allow a will save (which would definitely have given it away) but instead a perception check. Was this correct/is it truly DM interpretation?

Answer (score 5):

### Spiritual Weapon interacts with illusions normally

This is clarified in [Ultimate Intrigue](http://paizo.com/products/btpy9j6p?Pathfinder-Roleplaying-Game-Ultimate-Intrigue):

> **Disbelief and Interaction**: All three of the subschools
>   above tend to have saving throw lines that say “Will
>   disbelief,” but they differ in how those saving throws apply.
>   Phantasms directly assail a creature’s mind, so the
>   creature automatically and immediately receives a saving
>   throw to disbelieve a phantasm. Figments and glamers,
>   however, have the more difficult-to-adjudicate rule that
>   creatures receive a saving throw to disbelieve only if they
>   “interact” with the illusion.
>
> But what does it mean to interact with an illusion? It
>   can’t just mean looking at the illusion, as otherwise there
>   would be no need to make the distinction, but drawing
>   the line can be a bit tricky. Fortunately, the rules can
>   help to define that difference. **A creature that spends a
>   move action to carefully study an illusion receives a Will
>   saving throw to disbelieve that illusion**, so that is a good
>   benchmark from which to work.
>
> Using that as a basis, **interacting generally means
>   spending a move action, standard action, or greater on a
>   character’s part**. For example, if there were a major image
>   of an ogre, a character who tried to **attack the ogre would
>   receive a saving throw to disbelieve**, as would a character
>   who spent 1 minute attempting a Diplomacy check on
>   the ogre. A character who just traded witty banter with
>   the ogre as a free action would not, nor would a character
>   who simply cast spells on herself or her allies and never
>   directly confronted the illusory ogre. For a glamer,
>   interacting generally works the same as for a figment,
>   except that the interaction must be limited to something
>   the glamer affects. For instance, grabbing a creature’s ear
>   would be an interaction for a human using disguise self
>   to appear as an elf, but not for someone using a glamer
>   to change his hair color. Similarly, visually studying
>   someone would not grant a save against a glamer that
>   purely changed her voice.

It takes a move action to move the spiritual weapon to attack a new target, and casting the spell on a target takes a standard action, so the requirement is fulfilled here. So, if you spent some time to interact with the illusion, it counts as an interaction and you are allowed a save.